# User Control Animation Only Works On Last Declared Control Instance

Tags: xaml, animation, user-controls, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am proto-typing a (Windows 10 universal app) UI and have built a very simple/rough user control to act as a 'badge', i.e show a numeric value in a circle, and animate the value changing. My issue is the control works if there is only a single instance of it in an application page. If there are multiple instances (even if the other instances are invisible), then only the last declared instance animates.

I've tried declaring the animation both in the user control's XAML, and in code behind to attempt to ensure there's no cross-over/mix up with the animation being shared. I also added a change callback to the property being animated, which writes the property value out using Debug.WriteLine. For control instances that animate properly the value changes as expected, i.e if we go from 10 to 20, the property is set to 10, 11, 12, 13.... 20. For the instances that don't work, the value is just set to the from property every time, i.e 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.

Below is a sample of the user control, and then a sample page that uses three instances of it. Placing both of these is a new Windows 10 Universal app called App3 should reproduce the issue. In the sample page the first two badges don't animate properly when their button is clicked, but the last one does.

Is anyone able to point out what I'm doing wrong, and why this breaks with multiple instances on a page?

Thanks.

Note: The code has gotten quite rough as I've hacked things around trying to figure out what the issue is, and it was only prototype code to begin with, so I apologize for the mess.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App3.BadgeView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="20"
d:DesignWidth="20">
<Grid>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Border" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{Binding BadgeBorderBrush}" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="BadgeInner" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{Binding BadgeFillBrush}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="BadgeValue" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DisplayValue}" />
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class BadgeView : UserControl
{

    public DependencyProperty BadgeBorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BadgeBorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(BadgeView), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow)));
    public DependencyProperty BadgeFillBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BadgeFillBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(BadgeView), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange)));

    public DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(BadgeView), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));
    public DependencyProperty DisplayValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayValue", typeof(int), typeof(BadgeView), new PropertyMetadata(0, DisplayValueChanged));

    private static void DisplayValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((BadgeView)d).DisplayValue);
    }

    private Storyboard AnimateBadgeValueCount;
    private DoubleAnimation BadgeValueAnimation;

    public BadgeView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.BadgeValue.DataContext = this.BadgeInner.DataContext = this.Border.DataContext = this;

        AnimateBadgeValueCount = new Storyboard(); ;
        AnimateBadgeValueCount.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        Storyboard.AllowDependentAnimations = true;
        BadgeValueAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        BadgeValueAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        BadgeValueAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        BadgeValueAnimation.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

        this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
        this.BadgeValueAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
        AnimateBadgeValueCount.Children.Add(BadgeValueAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(AnimateBadgeValueCount, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimateBadgeValueCount, "DisplayValue");

        this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Completed += AnimateBadgeValueCount_Completed;
    }

    private void AnimateBadgeValueCount_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        this.DisplayValue = this.Value;
    }

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var badgeView = (BadgeView)d;

        badgeView.AnimateValue();
    }

    private void AnimateValue()
    {
        if (Value != DisplayValue)
        {
            this.BadgeValue.DataContext = this.BadgeInner.DataContext = this.Border.DataContext = this;

            this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Stop();
            this.BadgeValueAnimation.From = this.DisplayValue;
            this.BadgeValueAnimation.To = this.Value;
            this.BadgeValueAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
            //Storyboard.SetTarget(this.AnimateBadgeValueCount, this);
            //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(this.AnimateBadgeValueCount, "DisplayValue");
            this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Begin();
        }
    }

    public Brush BadgeBorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)this.GetValue(this.BadgeBorderBrushProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(this.BadgeBorderBrushProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Brush BadgeFillBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)this.GetValue(this.BadgeFillBrushProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(this.BadgeFillBrushProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int DisplayValue
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(DisplayValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(DisplayValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

}

<Page
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Content="Do it" x:Name="DoIt1" Click="DoIt1_Click" />
    <local:BadgeView x:Name="Badge1" Width="20" Height="20" BadgeFillBrush="Blue" />

    <Button Content="Do it" x:Name="DoIt2" Click="DoIt2_Click" />
    <local:BadgeView x:Name="Badge2" Width="20" Height="20" />

    <Button Content="Do it" x:Name="DoIt3" Click="DoIt3_Click" />
    <local:BadgeView x:Name="Badge3" Width="20" Height="20" />

</StackPanel>
```

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DoIt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Badge1.Value += 10;
    }

    private void DoIt2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Badge2.Value += 10;
    }

    private void DoIt3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Badge3.Value += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why instead animate the binding don't you try to animate the BadgeValue.Text? it is inside the control and you have the old value and the new value so I think is legal

Comment: I believe I can't (at least not directly), because .Text is a string, and doubleanimation won't animate that type. Since .Text might not be a number, it won't know how to increment it. Also, the animation works for one control instance, so I don't think the binding is the issue.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer as such but I have always found User controls a bit of a nightmare in xaml due to `DataContext` issues and have always preferred Custom Controls. I could put a simple example up later if interested but doesn't really answer your question

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I think I can probably build the custom control on my own, I just find user controls easier and haven't previously had a problem. Since this was only a prototype, I went with what I thought would be 'quickest' to develop. Even if I can solve this with an alternate plan, I'd still like to understand what is happening here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is simplify code and simplify and move the datacontext inside the loaded event inside the constructor:

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.DataContext = this;

            AnimateBadgeValueCount = new Storyboard(); ;
            AnimateBadgeValueCount.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
            BadgeValueAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            BadgeValueAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
            //BadgeValueAnimation.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
            AnimateBadgeValueCount.Children.Add(BadgeValueAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(AnimateBadgeValueCount, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(AnimateBadgeValueCount, "DisplayValue");

            this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Completed += AnimateBadgeValueCount_Completed;
        };


private async void AnimateValue()
    {
        if (Value != DisplayValue)
        {
            this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Stop();
            this.BadgeValueAnimation.From = this.DisplayValue;
            this.BadgeValueAnimation.To = this.Value;
            BadgeValueAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
             {
                 this.AnimateBadgeValueCount.Begin();
             });
        }
    }
```

I have commented the EasingFunction, it works but in my opinion fit betters. 
It is curious, because if I set the datacontext just in the constructor it works bad, but inside goes fine.
Tell me if you try.

Comment: Thank you. Moving the datacontext assignment to the loaded event does indeed solve the problem. I'm not sure why though... do you understand why this makes a difference?